# Can the electric potential of any body be calculated using the same formula?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential, coulombs-law

when doing problems i have seen that only $V=kq/r$ has been used. while for electric fields many other different formulas have been used. Does potential not matter with shape of body, if yes then why not?

Comment: In theory V-kq/r is all you need, but you need to know where all the other charges are and add up their contributions. That is what the formulas are for.

Comment: $kq/r$ is the potential of a point charge at the origin; similarly, $\vec E=(kq/r^2)\hat r$ is the field of a point charge at the origin. Other charge distributions are handled using superposition.

Comment: The answer to this is covered in absolutely any decent introduction to electrodynamics, Siam, even in Wikipedia. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential

Answer (score 0):

As $$\underbrace{\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_2^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_3^2} \right)}_{=:\Delta} \frac{1}{|\vec{x}-\vec{x}^\prime|}=-4 \pi \delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}-\vec{x}^\prime), \tag{1} \label{1}$$ the general solution of $$\Delta V(\vec{x})=-\rho(\vec{x})/\varepsilon_0 \tag{2} \label{2}$$ is given by $$V(\vec{x})= \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^3} \! d^3x^\prime \, \frac{\rho(\vec{x}^\prime)}{|\vec{x}-\vec{x}^\prime|}+ V_{\rm h}(\vec{x}), \tag{3} \label{3}$$ where $V_{\rm h}(\vec{x})$ is the general solution of the homogeneous equation $\Delta V_{\rm h}(\vec{x}) =0$ (usually restricted by certain boundary conditions). Using the relation  $\vec{E}(\vec{x})=-\vec{\nabla}V(\vec{x})$, the associated electric field is given by $$\vec{E}(\vec{x}) = \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0}\int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^3}\! d^3 x^\prime \, \rho(\vec{x}^\prime) \frac{\vec{x}-\vec{x}^\prime}{|\vec{x}-\vec{x}^\prime|^3} - \vec{\nabla} V_{\rm h}(\vec{x}). \tag{4} \label{4}$$ Although straightforward in principle, the evaluation of the integrals in \eqref{3} or \eqref{4} can become quite cumbersome already for relatively simple charge distributions. Therefore, for electrostatic problems with rotation or translation symmetries, it is often easier to compute the electric field employing $$\int\limits_{\partial V} d\vec{\sigma} \cdot \vec{E}(\vec{x}) = \frac{1}{\varepsilon_0} \int\limits _V \, d^3 x \, \rho(\vec{x})$$ for a certain suitable choice of the domain of integration $V$ together with the obvious symmetry properties of the electric field.